# Download most recent file of specific file name pattern from SFTP server

Tags: sftp, ls

I logged into a server using `sftp` and want to pick most recent file from the server with a specific pattern in name. I used this command for the same.

```
sftp -b <(echo "ls -1rt incoming/*pattern*") username@server | tail -1 | xargs -i bash -c 'sftp -b <(echo "get {}") username@server'
```

When I run the above command it does not get the most recent file with the pattern.

When I `sftp` to the server using `sftp username@server` from my unix box and do a `ls -lt *pattern*` the files are not listed by time. It seems random.

However when I connect to the server using `wincsp` client and order by time, it orders properly.

Any idea how to fix this.

Regards
Vaidy

Comment: NB When you find yourself fighting to make the command-line utilities do what you want, you should think about learning a more powerful scripting language like python or perl.